# how to pronounce name in japanese

Tags: pronunciation, hiragana

Would appreciate some help here. The picture shows a nametag that's meant to spell Reina in hiragana, but does the last character look off? Specifically the top right bar.

Additionally, do Japanese speakers pronounce this name as "Ray-na" or "Ray-ee-na?"

Many thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the nametag, it does clearly say れいな -- it's probably just the joins between the elements that are making it 'look off' to you? Perhaps seen from afar it would be clearer, as those small joins would appear less prominent?

As for pronunciation, Forvo is a good place to check for native pronunciation recordings. This individual says "Reina Miura" (apparently the name of a professional mixed martial artist). https://forvo.com/word/reina_miura/#ja

Answer (score 0):

There's a very slight difference between an English pronunciation and a Japanese pronunciation.
While the English pronunciation would be Ray-nuh, the Japanese pronunciation would be more like Re'ena. You hold the "eh" sound for a bit longer. The closest example in English that I can think of off the top of my head is the first "e" in "p*e*pe the frog".

As for the writing, yes, the font is heavily stylized. It would be better if the top right bar was slanted, instead of being completely horizontal.

Answer (score -2):

The easiest way to pronounce れいな for an English speaker would be "Ray-Na". And yes, the な　in the picture is very much incorrect. What font was used to make the plate?

Comment: What do you think is wrong with it? (Excluding areas where it has to be connected in order to just not fall apart).

Comment: I think if someone writes this way in a test a lot of teachers would mark it as incorrect, and students come off with a rather poor understanding of font stylisation as a result.

Comment: But... it's not a test... it's a piece of jewellery, and it's completely legible...